Doubt in application of Schur's lemma to understand morphism of representations
I am studying the connection between irreducible representations and degenerate eigenvalues, of say, a Hamiltonian. I am trying to follow a proof in the following passage:

Let me state the problem as I understand it. $(V,R)$ is a linear representation of a group $G$ and $H$ is an endomorphism of the representation, that is, $H : V \to V$ such that $H R(g) = R(g) H \quad \forall g \in G$. If the representation was irreducible, then Schur's lemma tells us that $H=E I$, as claimed in the passage.
But I am not able to follow the proof when $(V,R)$ is reducible, and in particular, when an irreducible representation is repeated. Let me give an example. Say $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$, where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are the same irreducible representation. (The subscripts are used just to distinguish them.) According to Schur's lemma, Hom$(V,V)$=Hom$(W_1,W_1) \oplus$ Hom$(W_1,W_2) \oplus$ Hom$(W_2,W_1) \oplus$ Hom$(W_2,W_2)$. Since $W_1 = W_2$, Schur's lemma tells us that the $i$th summands equals $\lambda_i I$, where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$. But according to the above passage, Hom$(W_1,W_2)=$Hom$(W_2,W_1)=0$. I don't understand why that must happen.
What am I missing out on?

Do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is the explanation of why you should not do this.

You aren't missing anything; the argument is simply not correct if the irreducibles have multiplicity. Generally speaking, I am sorry to say that physicists are very sloppy when it comes to group theory and representation theory and you should not try to learn these subjects from them.
What actually happens is the following. If $G$ is a group and $V$ is a (f.d.) completely reducible representation of that group over $\mathbb{C}$, then it decomposes into isotypic components corresponding to the irreducibles of $G$; one way to write this decomposition is
$$V \cong \bigoplus_i V_i \otimes M_i$$
where $V_i$ are the irreducibles and $M_i = \text{Hom}(V_i, V)$ are the multiplicity spaces. This is a basis-invariant way of discussing multiplicities. What Schur's lemma now implies is that if $H : V \to V$ is $G$-equivariant then it decomposes into a direct sum of maps $V_i \otimes M_i \to V_i \otimes M_i$ on each isotypic component, which are in turn of the form $\text{id}_{V_i} \otimes H_i$ where $H_i : M_i \to M_i$ is the induced map on multiplicity spaces, which can be arbitrary.
In the "multiplicity-$1$" case where $\dim M_i \le 1$ this recovers the statement in the lecture notes (since now each $H_i$ must be a scalar), but not in general. In the worst case $V$ is a trivial representation and then $H$ can be arbitrary.
In physics $V$ is additionally an inner product space, the action of $G$ is unitary, and $H$ is self-adjoint; in this case (sticking to the f.d. case for simplicity) $H$ is orthogonally diagonalizable by the spectral theorem, and even each $H_i : M_i \to M_i$ is orthogonally diagonalizable. So one can choose an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $H$ by choosing any orthonormal bases of the $V_i$, then an orthonormal basis for each $H_i : M_i \to M_i$, then tensoring them. With respect to such a basis $H$ is block diagonal with "large blocks" corresponding to each isotypic component and "smaller blocks" within these blocks corresponding to the multiplicities on the eigenvalues forced by tensoring with an orthonormal basis of $V_i$.
The conclusion I assume the author is trying to reach, which is still valid, is that the eigenvalues of $H$ have multiplicities at least as large as the dimensions of the irreducibles $V_i$ appearing in the decomposition. An easier way to see this which avoids everything we've just said above is to work in the other direction and argue that the eigenspaces $V_{\lambda} = \ker(H - \lambda I)$ are preserved by the action of $G$, so $V$ decomposes as a $G$-representation as a direct sum of the eigenspaces of $H$. Hence if the irreducible $V_i$ appears $m$ times in $V$ it must appear a total of $m$ times in each of these eigenspaces, which forces the eigenvalues of $H$ to have multiplicities of $\dim V_i$.
A spectacular example of this idea at work is that there is an action of $G = SO(4)$ (not just $SO(3)$!) on the eigenspaces of the Hamiltonian of an electron orbiting a proton, which can be used to explain the structure of the periodic table, in particular why the number of elements in each row $2, 8, 8, 18, 18, \dots$ is twice a square (these are twice the dimensions of irreducible representations of $SO(4)$!); see this MO thread and/or Singer's Linearity, Symmetry, and Prediction in the Hydrogen Atom for more on this.
